# Substitute for Microsoft Data Access ApplicationBlocks obsolete SqlHelper class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, enterprise-library

It looks that the old SqlHelper class from the Microsoft Enterprise Library
has been mostly replaced by the Database class which is included in the new Enterprise Library version 5.

I have a very simple and trivial example:

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data;

private void PopulateCheckBoxGroup()
 {
     const string strConnTxt = "Server=(local);Database=DataBindTests;Integrated Security=True;";
     const string strlSql = "select Technology from PreferredTechnology where ParentId = 1";
     CheckBoxList1.DataSource = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(strConnTxt, CommandType.Text, strlSql);
     CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "Technology";
     CheckBoxList1.DataBind();

 }
```

Can you give me just a hint in order to do the same using the new Database abstract class that replaced the SQLHelper?
I have looked into the Enterprise Library 5 "Hands On Labs" and there is no mention about it.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty much the same, just varies in its construction, e.g.:

```
var database = new SqlDatabase("<connection>");
using (var reader = database.ExecuteReader(...))
{

}
```

Comment: @Erica: Using the `SqlDatabase` directly has no real advantage over using the `SqlHelper` class. The `Database` class is used as an abstraction over database servers to be able to simply replace your data layer in an easy way. However, when you use direct queries instead of stored procedures to communicate with the database, there is no way to swap your data layer, because every database has its own dialect.